# Zend_Http_Client() equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, zend-framework

I found this server side Google Analytics, and I've been trying to convert it into C# code. Everything is going well, but I am not sure what the Zend_Http_Client would be in terms of .net.

I'm using the code here as the reference http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/ which was built in PHP with the Zend Framework(I assume).

Here are the two methods

```
    public function getHttpClient () {
        if(!$this->httpClient instanceof Zend_Http_Client) {
            include_once("Zend/Http/Client.php");
            $this->httpClient = new Zend_Http_Client();
            $this->httpClient->setConfig(array(
                'maxredirects' => 1,
                'timeout'      => 4
            ));
            $this->httpClient->setHeaders('Referer', "http://" . self::$trackingDomain . "/");
            $this->httpClient->setHeaders("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
            $this->httpClient->setCookieJar();
        }
        return $this->httpClient;
    }
```

and this

```
    private function requestHttp($url, $getParams = array())
    {
        $client = $this->getHttpClient();
        $client->setUri($url);
        $client->setParameterGet($getParams);
        $response = $client->request();

        if ($response->isSuccessful())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

My main concern is the setCokieJar(), MaxRedirects, and Timeouts, setParameterGet(), setURI(), and request()

So what the .net equivalent? WebClient? HttpWebResponse? HttpWebRequest? or is it something else?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) with some success before (I believe [`WebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) is just the counterpart to `WebRequest`). `WebClient` is easier to use but offers fewer options.

Comment: Any luck with adding additional parameters with the setParameterGet() in the Zend Class. I would need to send the Google Analytic information that's why I ask.

Comment: @Bombcode - What kind of additional parameters? Querystring? Form? Cookies? HTTP headers?

Comment: `GET` requests are just as simple as tacking on stuff to the URL. I believe for a `POST` request (someone correct me if I'm wrong) you would use [`UploadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y.aspx) and set the string to your desired query string. (Sort of weird, really; again, someone correct me if there's a better way.)

Comment: @Richard Szalay
I believe it's the Query String, I can set the cookies and http headers. But Google Analytic looks for items in the url that needs to be set. I believe in the request call, Zend_Http_Client will take your parameters and append them to the url. And then it will make the url request.

Comment: Okay I see whats going I can do that myself then, and will just send the response afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find an all-in-one equivalent, but `WebClient` is your best bet for a starting point. `HttpWebResponse` and `HttpWebRequest` are a little bit lower level than `WebClient`. `WebClient` has some excellent wrappers for making HTTP requests among other things.

Comment: Thanks when I checked out HttpWebRequest and HttpWebRequest in msdn they looked really good, but I wasn't sure how to add additional parameters to it.